# UIScrollView subviews are not filling up the scrollview. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Subviews added to my scrollView are not filling up the scrollview even though the constraints specify to go from edge to edge.

[image: Views not going from left edge to right edge]

```
 var containerScrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .green
        return scrollView
 }()

 let galleryView: GalleryView = {
        let view = GalleryView()
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.scrollRate = 4.5
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return view
    }()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     view.addSubview(containerScrollView)
     containerScrollView.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, leftConstant: 10, rightConstant: 10)

    // Setup Views
    // Only added 1 view to example to make code more readable, it also does not extend from edge to edge 

    containerScrollView.addSubview(galleryView)
    galleryView.anchor(top: headerView.bottomAnchor, left: containerScrollView.leftAnchor, right: containerScrollView.rightAnchor, topConstant: 18, heightConstant: view.frame.width / 1.5)
 }
```

---

The `anchor()` function is a function implemented by me which just makes it easier to add constraints to views, this function works fine and it is not causing the issue

I am not really sure where the problem is coming from so any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Assume that `UIScrollView` has 2 properties which are for its bounds and for its content. Unless `galleryView` has constraints to decide its size, the size of `UIScrollView`'s content will not set correctly.

Comment: can I manually set scrollview's content size like this: `scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: x, height: y)`?

Comment: Yes you can but not sure it will work with the `galleryView` which is a subview of the scroll view and which has constraints with scrollView's content view.

Comment: It will work if you set contenSize manually and set galleryView's frame manually instead of setting constraints on galleryView.

Comment: so I can't use any constraints inside scrollView? I just set the frames for the views? @Ryan

Comment: Nope. What you need is to set constraint precisely. If you add constraint on `galleryView` to have same width with `scrollView`'s frame width, the horizontal width will work as expected. But for the content height, you need to make `galleryView` decide its height.

Comment: @Ryan, I ended up creating a containerView that had the same frame as the scrollView and appended it to the scrollView and added all the subviews to it and it works great